# Model Building Issues in Microsoft.ML

Tags: c#, machine-learning, regression, microsoft.ml

I'm learning the Microsoft.ml framework, I tried to implement a simple model, but it produces very strange numbers. Tell me what I'm doing wrong:

```
    MLContext mlContext = new MLContext();

    IDataView trainingData = mlContext.Data.LoadFromEnumerable(data);

    var pipeline = mlContext.Transforms.Concatenate("Features", new[] {"R"})//, "R" 
        .Append(mlContext.Regression.Trainers.Sdca(labelColumnName: "P",  maximumNumberOfIterations: 1000));

    var model = pipeline.Fit(trainingData);

    var result = mlContext.Model.CreatePredictionEngine<EnterData, Prediction>(model).Predict(seachValue);

    return result;
```

The model is tuned for regression analysis of experimental data. I'm going to implement several network nodes, but for now I'm testing on a simple linear regression. In fact, the method should process the incoming data, train the model on it, make a prediction and return the answer to the test number.

The class wrapper is rolled out above. The problem is not in the message further down the code. There:

```
MessageBox.Show(result.P.ToString());
```

Answer (score -1):

Buddy, Your question is not clear. What is your model type ? Sentiment Analysis, Facial Recognition or Cost Prediction??
Whatever,  I think that the problem is issued in the last line of your code.

for example = return result.prediction();

Comment: You should leave a comment instead of posting an answer. If you don't have the rep to do so, rest assured that someone else will leave the appropriate comment. By submitting an answer like this you are only going to attract down votes, even if we agree with you ;)

Comment: Rethink about the final lines about your code, I think that the problem with your code is there,

Comment: Almost there :P put the Comment on the original post, not on your answer, ask for clarification that might guide them into the answer.  Then we delete this answer and these comments. When the original post is updated with a response to your question, then you will be able to write that killer solution. I'll watch this post and support your final solution with an up-vote.

Comment: Sent an update to the theme.

Closest to price prediction